# issue with empty slide in JSSOR Slider and goto currentIndex property not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, slider, refresh, jssor, caption

Hi I am working on JSSOR SLider and am trying to load a set of images on to it from database.

I am able to load therse images onto slider but i am getting first slide as an empty slide and rest are working fine.

In my index.html

```
<div data-role="main" id="galleryItemMainDetails">
    <!--blue-->
    <div id="MasterTemplate" style="min-width: 300px; min-height: 330px; background: #6699FF;">
        <!--purple-->
        <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 5px; width: 270px; height: 260px; background: #990099; overflow: hidden; ">

            <!-- Slides Container -->
            <!--light green-->
            <div id="HomeImgSliders" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: relative; overflow: hidden; left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 250px; height: 250px; background: #99FF99;">
                <div id="HomeSlides"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my js file

```
$('#galleryItem').on('pageshow', function () {
    var verticaltext = "";

    if ($('#galleryItem').has('#HomeImgSliders').length) {

        $("#HomeImgSliders").append("");

    }

    var allItems = Tables.images.all().order("capturedYear", false).order("capturedMonth", false).order("capturedDate", false);


    allItems.list(null, function (results) {
        var verticaltext = "";
        results.forEach(function (r) {

            // alert(JSON.stringify(r));
            imageDetailsarr.push([r.capturedDate, r.name, r.ratingTreatment, r.ratingSkinCleansing, r.ratingPlucking, r.ratingView, r.ratingLastVal, r.capturedDate, r.capturedMonth, r.capturedYear]);

            //  console.log("record is " + r.name);
            verticaltext = verticaltext + "<div><img alt='Image not found' src=" + r.name + " class='vSlideImg'/></div>"

            // <div><img  src=" + value[1] "></div>


        });

        $("#HomeImgSliders").append(verticaltext);
        // $("#HomeSlides").append(verticaltext);
        sliderDataReady(verticaltext);
 });


});
```

How can i get rid of this empty image that is appearing as the first slide

2) Also how can i set the slider set to a particular slide image based on some integer value that changes every time. I tried GoTO/slideIndex /currentIndex properties but could not get it ?

Any help would be appreciated ?Thanks

Comment: Please post full code here. The full html code of the slider, and event listen statements, and the evaluation of 'completeDate'

Comment: @Jssor. i have updated my code.please review and help

Answer (score 0):

Re 1: Please dump value of 'verticaltext', with it you can create a static slider to see why there is an empty slide.

Re 2: Please use $StartIndex option

```
var options = {
    ...,
    $StartIndex: 0,    //specify slide index to display at the beginning.
    ...
};
```